# Why recursive `let` make space effcient?

Tags: haskell, frp

I found this statement while studying Functional Reactive Programming, from ["Plugging a Space Leak with an Arrow"](http://cs-www.cs.yale.edu/homes/hl293/download/leak.pdf) by Hai Liu and Paul Hudak ( page 5) :

> ```
> Suppose we wish to deﬁne a function that repeats its argument indeﬁnitely:
>
>     repeat x = x : repeat x
>
> or, in lambdas:
>
>     repeat = λx → x : repeat x
>
> This requires O(n) space. But we can achieve O(1) space by writing instead:
>
>     repeat = λx → let xs = x : xs
>                   in xs
> ```

The difference here seems small but it hugely prompts the space efficiency. Why and how it happens ? The best guess I've made is to evaluate them by hand:

```
    r = \x -> x: r x
    r 3

    -> 3: r 3 
    -> 3: 3: 3: ........
    -> [3,3,3,......]
```

As above, we will need to create infinite new thunks for these recursion. Then I try to evaluate the second one:

```
    r = \x -> let xs = x:xs in xs
    r 3

    -> let xs = 3:xs in xs
    -> xs, according to the definition above: 
    -> 3:xs, where xs = 3:xs
    -> 3:xs:xs, where xs = 3:xs
```

In the second form the `xs` appears and can be shared between every places it occurring, so I guess that's why we can only require `O(1)` spaces rather than `O(n)`. But I'm not sure whether I'm right or not.

BTW: The keyword "shared" comes from the same paper's page 4:

> The problem here is that the standard call-by-need evaluation rules
>   are unable to recognize that the function:
>
> ```
> f = λdt → integralC (1 + dt) (f dt)
> ```
>
> is the same as:
>
> ```
> f = λdt → let x = integralC (1 + dt) x in x
> ```
>
> The former deﬁnition causes work to be repeated in the recursive call
>   to f, whereas in the latter case the computation is shared.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It's easiest to understand with pictures:

- The first version

  ```
  repeat x = x : repeat x
  ```

  creates a chain of `(:)` constructors ending in a thunk which will replace itself with more constructors as you demand them. Thus, O(n) space.

  [image: a chain]
- The second version

  ```
  repeat x = let xs = x : xs in xs
  ```

  uses `let` to "tie the knot", creating a single `(:)` constructor which refers to itself.

  [image: a loop]

Answer (score 39):

Put simply, variables are shared, but function applications are not. In

```
repeat x = x : repeat x
```

it is a coincidence (from the language's perspective) that the (co)recursive call to repeat is with the same argument. So, without additional optimization (which is called static argument transformation), the function will be called again and again.

But when you write

```
repeat x = let xs = x : xs in xs
```

there are no recursive *function* calls. You take an `x`, and construct a cyclic value `xs` using it. All sharing is explicit.

If you want to understand it more formally, you need to familiarize yourself with the semantics of lazy evaluation, such as [A Natural Semantics for Lazy Evaluation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.35.2016).

Answer (score 18):

Your intuition about `xs` being shared is correct. To restate the author's example in terms of repeat, instead of integral, when you write:

```
repeat x = x : repeat x
```

the language does not recognize that the `repeat x` on the right is the same as the value produced by the expression `x : repeat x`. Whereas if you write

```
repeat x = let xs = x : xs in xs
```

you're explicitly creating a structure that when evaluated looks like this:

```
{hd: x, tl:|}
^          |
 \________/
```